# Read serialized file associated with a program upon open

Tags: c#, wpf, file-extension

I have finished my program, serialized it for saving and created a fileopen system to open a file saved from my application. I have even created a file association with innosetup on the registry, which works perfectly fine.

All I want to achieve now is, whenever a user double click on a saved file from the program, the program should read and deserialize it.

For example, when you double click or open a .docx or .doc file, Microsoft Word is opened and the file is read and opened.  Presently my program will open, but I don't know how to detect when it is opened from a file so I can start deserialization.

Note: Deserializing itself is not the problem, it's detecting whether or not I should do so.

Answer (score 1):

When you start a program by double clicking on an associated file, the filename is passed in as a command line argument. You specify where this argument will occur in your file extension association setup.

If you set up your association as:

> program.exe %1

Double clicking your file will result in:

> program.exe C:\Folder\File.ext

This can be accessed using [`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx) or from your `Main(string[] args)` method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            // Get the argument
            string fileLocation = args[0];

            // Load and deserialize
            // Do the do
        }
    }
```

Here is an [MSDN article on command line arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Macropus, you actually didn't tell me what I did not know, you pointed a light to my error. This happens when I was setting the registry values on innosetup

instead of `{app}\program.exe %1` on innosetup I wrote, "{app}\program.exe" "%1"

which neglected the path to the file that opened the program.

So when I query `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();`

only the path to the program.exe is returned but now, both the program.exe and the path to the file to called the program is returned which is accessed from `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[1]`

To make this work when I open the file from a shortcut or the program.exe itself, 
I did

```
var comArgs = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
if (comArgs.Length > 1)
{
    // Then I can deserialize here.
}
```

Working now and thank you all.